# Margin interest deduction carryover when claiming standard deduction

Tags: united-states, income-tax, tax-deduction, form-1040

- Margin interest is a deductible investment expense on a US 1040 Schedule A as an itemized deduction
- Margin interest can be carried over year over year until it is fully deducted
- If the standard deduction exceeds a taxpayer's itemized deductions, they may opt to take the standard deduction instead of itemized Schedule A deductions

If a taxpayer opts to take the standard deduction, is the unclaimed margin interest carryable to future years where they may opt for Schedule A itemized deductions?

Answer (score 3):

No, it is not. The carryover is for the deductible interest that cannot be deducted because there's not enough investment income. You'll use the [form 4592](https://www.irs.gov/forms-pubs/about-form-4952) if that's the case. If you are not itemizing (even though you'd have enough investment income), then the interest is not deductible because you're forgoing the deduction altogether.

Comment: You can't carry it even if you do itemize on a future tax year when you aren't forgoing the deduction right? For that matter, do you lose any previously carried interest if you were itemizing, took the standard deduction for a year, then went back to itemizing?

Comment: @arcyqwerty not sure  I understand. So to clarify, in year X you spent $100 on investment interest, and got $0 investment income. You attach the form 4592 to your tax return and add the carried forward expanse to your expenses in year X+1. On the other hand, in year X you spent $100 on investment interest, had $100 investment income (making the interest currently deductible), but you chose standard deduction for the year X. That $100 investment interest expense is now lost to you.

Comment: I don't understand your explanation. My question is: [Can I carry forward investment interest expense even if I take the standard deduction?](https://money.stackexchange.com/q/158174/11877) Can you link to one or more authoritative sources, like IRS instructions or publications, to support your answer?

Comment: @ma11hew28 see the instructions to form 1040 (Schedule A) and form 4592. The standard deduction is an *election*, and if you're making it - you cannot double dip. You can only carry forward *disallowed* deduction, but if you *elect* to not deduct and take the standard deduction - it's not disallowed, you *chose* to not deduct it.