# Can I carry forward investment interest expense even if I take the standard deduction?

Tags: united-states, investing, tax-deduction, interest, form-1040

On IRS 2022 Form 1040, if I take the standard deduction, I don’t think I’m allowed to deduct investment interest expense on Schedule A, line 9, but can I still file Form 4952 to report any disallowed investment interest expense to be carried forward to 2023?